# Помогите нарисовать пружинку черепашкой. Не вызывается функция внутри цикла другой функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, turtle

[image: Вот такую пружинку надо нарисовать]

```
import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.tracer(0,0)

def duga_small():
    for i in range(0,50,2):
    turtle.fd(0.1)
    turtle.left(7.2)
def duga_big():        
    turtle.setheading(90)
    count=0
    x=2
    while count<3:
        for i in range(0,100,2):
        turtle.fd(x)
        turtle.right(3.6)
    duga_small() #<-- почему вызов этой функции игнорируется при рисовании?
    count+=1
duga_big()
turtle.update()
```

Comment: У вас именно так расставлены пробелы?
Вы используете только пробелы, без табов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while count<3:
        for i in range(0,100,2):
            turtle.fd(x)
            turtle.right(3.6)
        duga_small() #<-- возможно,у вас проблемы с пробелами
        count+=1
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Переписал еще раз с Вашим примером, и заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Можно без функций, это проще:

```
import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.speed(3)
turtle.penup()
turtle.setx(-450)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.circle(-100, 180)
    turtle.circle(-20, 180)
turtle.circle(-100, 180)
turtle.done()
```